# Import Ecoinvent 2.2 Ecospold files into Brightway

Tags: brightway

I was trying to use the following code (Figure.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtWMb.png)) to import Ecoinvent v2.2 into Brightway. I followed code from: https://github.com/PoutineAndRosti/Brightway-Seminar-2017/blob/master/Day%201%20AM/2%20-%20BW%20structure%20and%20first%20LCAs.ipynb

I obtained all XML (ecospold files) downloaded from Simapro (which is connected to ecoinvent database) and save all datafiles into the folder: C:\bw2-python\ecoSpold1.

However, when I run the next step, I ran into the following errors:
Figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiBUV.png)

I am not sure what is wrong here. Any suggestion would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I think the ecospold files obtained from simapro and from the ecoinvent website are not the same. Simapro codes things a bit differently, which I think affects the naming of exchanges (that is why you got an invalid exchange). You either download the ecospold files from ecoinvent or use the tools see notebooks [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2/raw/default/notebooks/IO%20-%20student%20project%20SimaPro%20export.ipynb) and [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2/raw/default/notebooks/IO%20-%20SimaPro%20export%20with%20ecoinvent.ipynb) to read exported csv files (the format prefered by simapro to export datasets).